# Convert string to date with different types of time format

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a dataframe as bellow

```
library(lubridate) 
Date <- c("18.11.2016 21:03:41", "19.11.2016", "20.11.2016","21.11.2016")
df = data.frame(Date) 
df
```

I to get

```
df$Date
[1] "2016-11-18" "2016-11-19" "2016-11-20" "2016-11-21"
```

& try to convert it to date like this

```
df$Date = dmy(df$Date)
```

and I get

```
Warning message:
 1 failed to parse.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Try `parse_date_time(Date, c("dmy", "dmy_HMS"))`

Comment: Or `as.Date(Date, "%d.%m.%Y")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
s <- c("2004-03-21 12:45:33.123456",    # ISO
       "2004/03/21 12:45:33.123456",    # variant
       "20040321",                      # just dates work fine as well
       "Mar/21/2004",                   # US format, also support month abbreviation or full
       "rapunzel")                      # will produce a NA

p <- toPOSIXct(s)

options("digits.secs"=6)                # make sure we see microseconds in output
print(format(p, tz="UTC")
```

Read about it more [here](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/parsing-datetimes/).

Comment: @RichScriven Yeah https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppbdt/blob/master/demo/toPOSIXct.R

Comment: @RichScriven A bit of overkill for this job, but still no harm in trying I guess

Comment: I installed library(RcppBDT) but 
> p <- toPOSIXct(s)
Error: could not find function "toPOSIXct"